# When $f=u+iv$ is a holomorphic function, the real part of $f'(z)$ is equal to $u_x(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, partial-derivative

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic, and is written as $f=u+iv$ with $u,v$ real-valued.
Why is the partial derivative   $u_x(z)$ equal to $\operatorname{Re}(f'(z))$?

#### Source

This fact is used in the proof linked below, at the line that starts with "By assumption, $f'(z)=0$...)

- [The proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBhBX.jpg)
- [A theorem mentioned in the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvc4i.jpg)
- [Another theorem mentioned in the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8r55.jpg)

Comment: Too many screenshots make the post unduly long. I changed  them to links, since they are not necessary to understand the actual question.

Comment: Thanks bro.  I appreciate it.  I'd upvote you if I could.

Answer (score 3):

Recall the definition of complex derivative:
$$
f'(z) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h} \tag1
$$
In the definition, $h$ can be any complex number. Let's focus on *real* $h$ only: $h=t$, $t\in\mathbb R$ 
$$
f'(z) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(z+t)-f(z)}{t}  
$$
Plug $f=u+iv$ into this limit and separate the real and imaginary parts (this is where it helps that $t$ is real): 
$$
f'(z) = \lim_{t\to 0 } \frac{u(z+t)-u(z)}{t} + i \lim_{t\to 0 } \frac{v(z+t)-v(z)}{t}
$$
The limits are just the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ with respect to $x$ variable. So,
$$
f' = u_x + iv_x
$$
from where the claim follows.

---

For completeness, let's now take purely imaginary values of $h$, that is $h=it$, $t\in\mathbb R$. Then (1) becomes
$$
f'(z) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(z+it)-f(z)}{it}  
$$
Again, separate real and imaginary parts:
$$
f'(z) = -i \lim_{t\to 0 } \frac{u(z+it)-u(z)}{t} +   \lim_{t\to 0 } \frac{v(z+it)-v(z)}{t}
$$
and so 
$$f' = -iu_y+v_y$$